# Getting error message with koa.js + axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, koa

I am using [koa.js](http://koajs.com/) for back-end and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for http requests in front-end. I want to set up error message in koa.js and get the error message in front-end, but I get only default error message *"Request failed with status code 500"*

**koa.js api call**

```
module.exports.addIntr = async (ctx, next) => {
  const intrObj = ctx.request.body;
  try {
    intrObj = await compileOneInterest(intrObj);
    ctx.response.body = intrObj;
  } catch (err) {
    const statusCode = err.status || 500;
    ctx.throw(statusCode, err.message);
  }
};
```

[image]

**http request with axios**

```
export function addInter(interObj) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const url = `${API_ADDRESS}/ep/${10}/intr/`;

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url,
      data: interObj,
      // params: {
      //   auth: AccessStore.getToken(),
      // },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(addIntrSuccess(response.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(handlePoiError(error.message));
        console.log(error.response);
        console.log(error.request);
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Main issue** `compileOneInterest` function throws array instead Error object. On your screenshot err is `[{message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34}]`. Your try block is running:

```
const statusCode = err.status || 500; // undefined || 500 
ctx.throw(statusCode, err.message); // ctx.throw(500, undefined);
```

So you see default message.

2) You use error-like object instead `new Error('message')` or `CustomError('message', 34)`

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(message, code) {
    super(message);
    this.code = code;
  }
}
```

Best practise is throw Errors or custom Error object.

3) Your statusCode calculation use `err.status` instead `err.code`.